# How to implement SSE in Mule 3.9.0 using http listener and jersey

Tags: jersey, mule, server-sent-events, httplistener

Is it possible to implement server sent events (SSE) with mule (3.9.0) and jersey? It seems that the mule http listener immediately closes the connection. Is there a way for mule to keep the socket open?

I have implemented the configuration:

```
<http:listener-config name="HttpListenerConfig" host="0.0.0.0" basePath="/myservice" port="8090" />

<flow name="NotificationServiceFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HttpListenerConfig" path="/sse/*" allowedMethods="GET" parseRequest="false" responseStreamingMode="ALWAYS">
        </http:listener>
        <jersey:resources>
            <component>
                <spring-object bean="NotificationResource"/>
            </component>
        </jersey:resources>
    </flow>
```

and the jersey resource as follows:

```
@Path("/notifications")
public class NotificationResource {
    
    private SseBroadcaster broadcaster = new SseBroadcaster();
    
    @GET
    @Produces(SseFeature.SERVER_SENT_EVENTS)
    public EventOutput subscribe() {
        final EventOutput eventOutput = new EventOutput();
        broadcaster.add(eventOutput);
        return eventOutput;
    }
    
    public void broadcast(String json) {
        OutboundEvent.Builder builder = new OutboundEvent.Builder();
        OutboundEvent event = builder
            .mediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
            .data(String.class, json)
            .build();
        broadcaster.broadcast(event);
    }
}
```

Comment: If it is not possible with mule 3.9.0, can it be implemented with mule 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server side events are not supported in any version of Mule as far as I know.

An alternative could be to use Mule 4 Websockets connector: https://docs.mulesoft.com/websockets-connector/1.0/

In any cases using Mule 3.9.0 is unsafe. It is recommended to migrate to the latest release of Mule 4.